# foreach loop in php

Tags: php

```
$browsers = $day1;
foreach($browsers as $browser) 
{
    echo "<input type='checkbox'/>$browser";
}
```

When I use this code, it gives me output in single line, but I want to print two entries in single line and other in after the break.

Example:

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
```

Can anyone tell me how can we use a line-break in loop?

Comment: `$browsers as $i => $browser` and then use a condition for $i to break it

Comment: Can you please be more spesific?

Comment: Can you put your pencils on the table in groups by two? The algorithm is **exactly the same**

Comment: @Joseadrian, that should be an answer. It would be the best one, but as a comment it might not be noticed.

Answer (score 1):

If this is the output you want:

```
browser1 browser2
browser3 browser4
...
browserN-1 browserN
```

You could try this:

```
$bIndex = 0;
foreach($browsers as $browser) 
{
    echo "<input type='checkbox'/>$browser";
    if (($bIndex % 2) == 1) { // only true for odd bIndex values
        echo "<br>";
    }
    $bIndex++;
}
```

Comment: You could also do `foreach($browsers as $bIndex => $browser)` if it's a numerical array.

Answer (score 0):

From what you're saying, I think you mean you want to have each checkbox and label on a new line.

```
foreach($browsers as $browser){
    echo '<p><input type="checkbox" /><label>'.$browser.'</label></p>';
}
```

Ofcourse, you'd want to be adding a `name` attribute on each the input tags (and the `label` tags), if you wanted to be able to process them on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

If I got you correctly you want to show two in each line than after a break, try this

```
echo "<p>";
for($i=0;$i<count($browsers);$i++) {
if($i>0 && ($i%2==0)) { echo "</p><p>"; }
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='browser[".$browsers[$i]."]' /><label>".$browsers[$i]."</label>";
}
echo "</p>";
```

Edit for comment:

if it's not enumerated, still easy:

```
$i=0;
echo "<p>";
foreach ($browsers as $randomstuff=>$browser) { //or whatever array structure.
if($i>0 && ($i%2==0)) { echo "</p><p>"; }
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='browser[".$browsers."]' /><label>".$browsers."</label>";
$i++;
}
echo "</p>";
```

Comment: what if $browsers is not enumerated list?

Comment: $kbrowser = array_keys($browsers);  $browsers[$kbrowser[$i]]

Comment: Updated the anser for the situations where it's not enumerated.

Comment: thanks can you tell me one more thing how can we submit the checked value in the database. because i want to submit the value of all checked in the database.

Comment: Updated the code once again. After you submit, values will be sent as an array. e.g: For PHP, it'll be like $_POST['browser'] which will be an array, and with a foreach or for loop (like in the question or the examples) or with serializing you can process the data.

Comment: thanks once again can you tellme one more thing. no value will be post in the database only a aary will be post. but i can want to send the checked values in the database